# Automatically load map in R from script on startup error

Tags: r, dictionary, startup

I've been trying to get this working without any luck (I'm new to R so don't really know how to do much and have been following examples). Basically I have an R script created that will automatically load a map when run, saved as .R file:

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(mapdata)
map('worldHires', 
       c('UK', 'Ireland', 'Isle of Man','Isle of Wight'), 
        xlim=c(-11,3), ylim=c(49,60.9))
```

I want this to happen automatically when I open the `RGui` without having to go to load script, and then select run all. I've read about editing the `Rprofile.site file` which I've done and I've added an entry to it:

```
.First <- function(){
    library(maps)
    library(maptools)
    library(mapdata)
    map('worldHires', 
        c('UK', 'Ireland', 'Isle of Man','Isle of Wight'), 
        xlim=c(-11,3), ylim=c(49,60.9))
}
```

However, when I start R, I think it loads the libraries but then it says:

```
Error in maptype(database) : could not find function "data"
```

and no map is produced. However it works perfectly fine when I load the script manually and then press run all.

Am I doing something wrong here? Does the `.First` function only load packages? What would make it work? I've also tried just using `source(script location)` in the first function and that gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are getting is that `.First` scripts can only use functions in the `base` package, unless the packages have been explicitly loaded. So in your case, you need to load

- `utils` for the `data` function.
- `graphics` for the `par` function.

Putting this together gives:

```
.First <- function() {
    library(utils); library(graphics)

    library(maps)
    library(maptools)
    library(mapdata)
    map('worldHires', 
        c('UK', 'Ireland', 'Isle of Man','Isle of Wight'), 
        xlim=c(-11,3), ylim=c(49,60.9))
}
```